# @SessionScoped CDI bean is a different Instance when injected

Tags: servlets, javabeans, cdi, apache-tomee

My config is a bean that I inject in my code wherever I need it. However, when injected, I get a new instance of the bean instead of the one from the session.

**My bean:**

```
@Named
@SessionScoped
public class TestModel implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 4873651498076344849L;

    private String version;

    public String getVersion() {
        return version;
    }

    public void setVersion(String version) {
        this.version = version;
    }

    public void changeVersion() {       
        this.version = "Version 2";
        System.out.println("New version : " + version + ", Object : " + this);
    }
}
```

When injected in different classes, all occurences are different instances.
When annotating the bean with @ApplicationScoped, it is the same instance.

I do need the bean to be @SessionScoped since every user should have his own config.

The WebApp is running on TomEE 1.7.4

**UPDATE: I created a new project to test it, and the SessionScope works. I now need to find out what is wrong with my current project in order to fix it.**

**Facets:**

- CDI 1.0
- Dynamic Web Module 3.0
- Java 1.8
- JSF 2.2 (MyFaces impl from TomEE)
- JPA 2.1

**Web.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0">
  <display-name>Project</display-name>
  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>
  <context-param>
    <description>State saving method: 'client' or 'server' (=default). See JSF Specification 2.5.2</description>
    <param-name>javax.faces.STATE_SAVING_METHOD</param-name>
    <param-value>client</param-value>
  </context-param>
  <context-param>
    <param-name>javax.servlet.jsp.jstl.fmt.localizationContext</param-name>
    <param-value>resources.application</param-value>
  </context-param>
  <context-param>
    <param-name>primefaces.THEME</param-name>
    <param-value>omega</param-value>
  </context-param>
  <context-param>
    <param-name>javax.faces.PROJECT_STAGE</param-name>
    <param-value>Development</param-value>
  </context-param>
  <context-param>
    <param-name>javax.faces.FACELETS_SKIP_COMMENTS</param-name>
    <param-value>true</param-value>
  </context-param>
  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.xhtml</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

**faces-config.xml**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<faces-config
    xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-facesconfig_2_2.xsd"
    version="2.2">

</faces-config>
```

**beans.xml**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/beans_1_1.xsd"
       version="1.1" bean-discovery-mode="annotated">           
</beans>
```

Any ideas ?

Comment: I guess that the problem is a session scope. Because you might have modified a different `Config` (from another session). Please change it to `Singleton` or `ApplicationScoped` and check if problem still exists.

Comment: Glad it worked but since `Singleton` and `ApplicationScoped` are basically the same, how did you solve your problem, when every user shall have his own config?

Comment: You are right. I tried with two simultaneous sessions, and the values updated for every user. So back to square one. On session scoped, the value does not get updated in the servlet :-(

Comment: But to be honest: this doesn't make sense. `SessionScoped` should work just fine. Please make sure that during your tests you're using the same HTTP session for both requests (`request.getSession().getId()` has to be the same).

Comment: You found the problem. The ID is not the same. How to fix this ? I sent the request from the same browser window just after updating the config.

Comment: But did the config was updated in the same browser window? Or did you invalidate your session somewhere in your code?

Comment: I have a webapp with xhtml pages. Config.xhtml is used to update the config. The servlet runs in the background of that webapp.

Comment: Then I guess your `config.xhtml` doesn't update the `Config` object you think. Please update your question and include also some info how you use this config object on your page (and how `Config` bean is declared)

Comment: If the session id is different each time, your problem lies there. Find out why the session is new/different each time...

Comment: All right, I fixed the session ID. Still got the problem. Updating the first post.

Comment: What is the fully qualified name of @SessionScoped annotation? Is it `javax.enterprise.context` or `javax.faces.bean`?

Comment: javax.enterprise.context

Comment: I am getting two different IDs when comparing HttpServletRequest.getSession().getId() vs FacesContext..getExternalContext().getSession.getId(). Shouldn't it be the same ?

Comment: Any more suggestions ? I am about to give up

Comment: Try in a different container? E.g. wildfly (and read carefully, I stated **try**, not use/switch in production). Then you know if the the container is the problem or not

Comment: I know, but I have to use TomEE anyway. So if it does not work with it, I'll need to find a workaround. And accorting to Silarius, it works with Wildfly

Comment: Update: I found out that it is not limited to my servlet, but that the whole @SessionScoped does not work.

Comment: Found a similar case: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14581666/example-for-cdi-sessionscoped-login-with-tomee

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like your test doesn't work:

```
testModel object = model.TestModel@689a6064
New version : Version 2, Object : model.TestModel@61606aa6
```

So you update an instance which is not the same as the one linked to the session (another request not reusing the same session I'd say)

Comment: Well that's the problem. The bean I am updating when changing the version is not the same as the one injected in the Servlet. But it should be the same. Or I did not understand your comment

Comment: My comment was you don't show how you call "changeVersion()" so it can be you don't reuse the same session

Answer (score 1):

**You are doing it right**. That is, from CDI perspective, you made no mistake and what you want is perfectly legit and should work (assuming you solved the problem of multiple sessions, which you did).

I just tried this with my own piece of code and it works as expected. You can [check it on GitHub](https://github.com/manovotn/core/tree/SO_question/tests-arquillian/src/test/java/org/jboss/weld/tests/contexts/session/servlet). The sample is more or less identical to yours.

**However**, I am running Wildfly 10 and therefore Weld 2.3 which comes with it (Weld being a reference impl of CDI). While you are running **TomEE which contains OpenWebBeans** (another CDI implementation).

To me it seems like you either missed some TomEE/OWB specific configuration (unrealistic scenario) or, more likely, you found a bug. In any case, if I were you, I would try asking on their forums or creating an issue in their [tracking system](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/owb) because, once again, there is imho nothing wrong with your bean/servlet setup.

Comment: Thanks. I also have a Wildfly 10, I'll try it too. Then I'll ask OpenWebBeans. I'll let you know

Comment: I am not sure about the sessions after all: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38718106/httpservletrequest-getsession-getid-vs-facescontext-getexternalcontext-ge

Answer (score 0):

We have `@SessionScope` annotation in both JSF & CDI. Please review whether the annotation you are using in your old project is from JSF or from CDI.
Find more on the [difference between the annotation from JSF & CDI](https://www.javacodegeeks.com/2015/11/jsf-scopes-tutorial-jsfcdi-session-scope.html)