# Bean scope hierarchy and dependence?

Tags: jsf, scope, cdi

I am having problems understanding a few scope concepts.

**Let's say I have this Bean (used in a xhtml):**

```
@Named
@RequestScoped
public class ConfigController implements Serializable {

    @Inject
    ConfigModel config; // Bean is @SessionScoped
}
```

If a ConfigController is created for each http request, what about the injected ConfigModel inside ? Does it keep its values, or is it recreated with the controller ? (I doubt it ?)

What if a ConfigModel is injected in multiple beans with different scopes ?

As I gathered, the scope hierarchy should go from **broad to narrow:**
- Models should be session scoped, since they contain the data
- Controllers (and services below) can be request scoped, since they only implement logic.

This is the original problem I am facing:
[@SessionScoped CDI bean is a different Instance when injected](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38661685/cdi-bean-is-not-updated-when-injected-in-a-servlet)

Comment: The ConfigModel would be new for each Session if it is Session Scoped. If you want to go from narrow to broad you can use an [Instance](https://docs.jboss.org/cdi/api/1.1/javax/enterprise/inject/Instance.html) `Object.`

Comment: _"If a ConfigController is created for each http request, what about the injected ConfigModel inside ? Does it keep its values, or is it recreated with the controller ? (I doubt it ?)"_ Try... And yes this normally works.

Comment: Since someone marked it as duplicate before I could post answer, I'll at least add a simple comment.
As long as you are within the same **session**, you get to inject the same `@SessionScoped` bean (`ConfigModel` in your case). Once you, for example, `invalidate()` that session and start sending new requests (hence creating new session), all the requests will get a newly created session injected. The original problem which led you here might have been caused by creating several sessions, but that is just my guess.

Comment: @BalusC is it now? I was answering the part when OP asks "Does it keep its values, or is it recreated with the controller ?". So nope, it is an aswer to this one with a hint to the original one.